# scala create new list by omitting the n element from existing list with tuples

Tags: list, scala

I new in scala so please try to elaborate.

I have a list such as:

```
val trioElmList = List((10,20,30),(50,89,90),(60,40,65))
```

How can I get a new list with the middle element of each tuple omitted? The result should be:

```
newList : List[(Int, Int)] = List((10,30), (50,90), (60,65))
```

Comment: If you want transform every element in a sequence the very first option is always `map`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the map method to apply a function to each element of the list and create a new list with the return values of that function. In the function, you use pattern matching to get the elements of the tuple and return a tuple with only the first and last element.

```
trioElmList.map { case (x,y,z) => (x,z) }
```

Answer (score -2):

No any `case` is needed if your `List` was appropriately typed.

```
val l: List[Tuple3[_, _, _]] = List((1,2,3), (2,3,4), (3,4,5))
l map (e => (e._1, e._3))
```

Comment: Trying to go a statically-typed way of manipulating things, is bad? I will downvote too if noone of you 2 will explain why.

Comment: Using a wildcard for the tuple argument types is both completely unnecessary and gets one in trouble.  This doesn't help the list be typed correctly--in fact, it ensures that it will not be!  (The resulting list is typed with `(Any, Any)` tuples when they should be `(Int, Int)`.

Comment: Right, we only knew that we have tuple3 of something. And wanted to have tuple2 of something.